# XmlReader not reading Xml result from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns data in Xml. Originally the root node was the table name itself. I also made a change so that the root node is "xml".

In the stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
FOR XML PATH('mytable'), ROOT('xml'), ELEMENTS;
```

The same problem occurs when reading the result as follows:

```
string xmlresult = string.Empty;

using (var command = (SqlCommand)connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "sp_dosomething";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            xmlresult = reader.ReadOuterXml();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

> Invalid command sent to ExecuteXmlReader.  The command must return an Xml result.

at:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteXmlReader(SqlDataReader ds)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide your xml and stored procedure .

Comment: @RonakPatel The xml and sp are quite complex but I'll add how I'm returning the xml.

Comment: you need to at-least provide demo xml so i can help you .

Comment: What type of data is inside `mytable`?

Comment: @DanielMinnaar Normal datatypes like int, varchar, bit, money. No text, image or xml columns.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono The reason I ask is because your code works for me. I copied it verbatim and `xmlresult` populates as a string fine with the table I'm using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it is clear that what you are getting is not an XML result.

Instead of using ExecuteXmlReader() try using **ExecuteReader()** to get the output and see. Definitely it would not be a nice XML.

```
// execute the command
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// iterate through results, printing each to console
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Print the data here and check output will not be XML in your case");
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the exception is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'. Note: A few nodes in the xml are `uniqueidentifier`. It still doesn't return the complete xml.

Comment: Simple suggestion, points to the correct debugging direction.